# make a counter in react js and get start stop time and date

Tags: reactjs

can any one make me a counter that starts when i click on `start button` and stop when i click `stop button` and also save the clicked time and date in a variable

i want it in functional compontent

```
      <h2>timer </h2>
  
          <div onClick={startcount}>
           
          
            <button>Start</button>
          
           
            <br />
            <button>Stop</button>
          </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live link to test: https://z2pb6.csb.app/
And here is the code:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [begin, setBegin] = useState(false);
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState(null);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => setBegin((prev) => !prev);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (begin) {
      setTimestamp(new Date().toString());
      // clearing prev interval
      intervalRef?.current && clearInterval(intervalRef.current);

      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, 1000);
      intervalRef.current = intervalId;
    } else {
      setCount(0);
      intervalRef?.current && clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [begin]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>timer {timestamp}</h2>
      {count}
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Start</button>

        <br />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Stop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: how to get start time and date and stop time and date .also i want counter to show both seconds and mill secondss

Comment: @MeenuKs have a look now.

Comment: @MeenuKs in case you want to record stop time as well so you can go with approach mentioned by mouafus

Comment: yes i want to record both stop time also iwant the counter  to reset to 0 when i click on stop

Comment: @MeenuKs I have made few changes, it'll reset to 0 now. When the counter is paused you can reset the counter back to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state to store te start and the stop value. like this:

```
const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState({
  start: null,
  stop: null
});
```

When the user click on start button, store the current time

```
<button onClick={()=>setTimerState({...timerState, start: new Date()})} >Start</button>
```

When ther user click on stop

```
<button onClick={()=>setTimerState({...timerState, stop: new Date()})} >Stop</button>
```

Comment: how to show the counter

Comment: how do you want count ? by second or by minute ?

Comment: start time ,date and stop time, date .also i want counter to show both seconds and mill seconds, iwant the counter to reset to 0 when i click on stop

Answer (score 0):

you can create counter with single state and useEffect

````
const Counter = () => {
  const [counterObject, setCounterObject] = React.useState({
    counter: 0,
    CounterCountDown: false
  });

  const startCount = () => {
    setCounterObject({
      CounterCountDown: true,
      counter: counterObject.counter
    });
  };
  const stopCount = () => {
    setCounterObject({
      CounterCountDown: false,
      counter: counterObject.counter
    });
  };
  const resetCount = () => {
    setCounterObject({
      CounterCountDown: false,
      counter: 0
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counterObject.CounterCountDown) {
      let startCounter = setInterval(() => {
        setCounterObject({
          CounterCountDown: true,
          counter: counterObject.counter + 1
        });
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(startCounter);
      };
    }
  }, [counterObject]);

  return (
    <div >
    <div>{counterObject.counter}</div>
      <button onClick={startCount}>Start Count</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button onClick={resetCount}>Reset Count</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button onClick={stopCount}>stop Count</button>
    </div>
  );
}```
````